# How to retrieve has passwords from database an assign as var for auth

Tags: php, hash, mysqli

I have a user database with a hashed passwords. I want to use the `password_verify()` to check the form password input against the hash within the database.

```
$password = $_POST['password'] ;
$stored_password = '$2y$10$5tk/g7rsGBiqUd5jBuwu2OspNGa18BZ1YxOcx8EdZETE2rtY5xPe2';

if (password_verify($password, $stored_password)) {
    echo "Passwords match";
}
else {
    echo "Passwords do not match";
}
```

Like this but obviously the hash is assigned to a variable here and not drawn from the DB.

How do I restructure using mysqli query?

I have had a go and come up with this, but its still not quite there as is not recognising that the passwords do match on hash.

```
<?

$username_check = $_POST['username'];
$password_check = $_POST['password'];

require 'db_connect.php';

if ($result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM business_info WHERE username = '$username_check'")) {

    if($count = $result->num_rows) {

        // echo $count;


        $rows = $result->fetch_assoc();
        // echo '<pre>', print_r($rows), '<pre>';

        }

    }   

    $hashed_pass = $rows['password'];

    if (password_verify($password_check, $hashed_pass)) {

        echo "Passwords match";
    }
    else {

        echo "Passwords do not match";
    }


    echo $rows['password'];

?>
```

Comment: Any attempts of your own so far or...?

Comment: i know the theory of SELECT * FROM WHERE but im very new to it.

Comment: Google it. You stand at being led back to questions and answers on Stack. Plus, look over to the right under Related >>>

Comment: Alright, fair enough. A brief overview. You'd need something like SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE unique_user_identifier(could be an ID for example) = something. Start with that.

Comment: Google this > "password_verify compare mysqli php"

Answer (score 0):

You have a hash password stored in your db. Let it be $stored_pass.
user post his/her password via form. Let it be $_POST['password'].
Now do hash of  $_POST['password'] and check it with $stored_pass.
Like

```
if($stored_pass == your_hash_function($_POST['password']))
{
  true
}
else
{
false
}
```

[php password hash link to php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: edited original post with an attempt but still not quite there cant se what the problem is....

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way but you will get the point:

```
<?php //always add php

$db_username = "user";
$db_password = "pass";

$db_name = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$password = $_POST['password'] ;
$username = $_POST['username'] ;

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $stored_password = $row["password"];
        break; //Because we know we have one result.
    }
} else {
    echo "No such user.";
}


if (password_verify($password, $stored_password)) {

    echo "Passwords match";
}
else {

    echo "Passwords do not match";
}
```

In production, you need to use [Prepared Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: edited original post with an attempt but still not quite there cant se what the problem is....